# watir-webdriver click on image

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

Folks,

I have an image with the following HTML code:

```
<div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-unselectable" style="; text-align: right;" id="ext-gen1453">
<img alt=""src="data:image/gif;base64,FRFRFR/GFFFFFFFFFF==" class="x-action-col-icon x-action-col-0 folder-action-add folder-action" data-qtip="Add New Music File" id="ext-gen1300">
```

When I click on the image it should open a pop up so that I can add new music file, I tried a few things but I am not able to click on that image. Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you show us the code that you've tried so far?  And also what you mean by 'I am not able to click' - does an error occur?  Or do you just not see the expected result?

Comment: thanks for the response Jon, I tried this `@browser.image(:text => "Add New Music File").click` and I get the error `unable to locate element, using {:tag_name=>"img", :text=>"Add New Smart Folder"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)`

Comment: Have you tried locating the element by ID (in this case 'ext-gen1300')?  The markup doesn't actually have a `text` attribute, only a `data-qtip` one so it's not surprising that the code you pasted above doesn't find it

Comment: What is this button you speak of?

Comment: mark, i updated it, i meant image

Comment: Jon, I tried locating the element by ID, this is my code snippet `@browser.image(:id => "ext-gen1300").click` , this does not work. I still get the error `unable to locate element, using {:tag_name=>"img", :id=>"ext-gen1300"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)`

Comment: the thing is the ID is generated dynamically and changes each time.

Comment: Show us more of the HTML.   There might be a sibling element in the div that could be used to identify it.  Also the class of the containing div makes me thinks this might be part of some fancy control and perhaps you might have to do something like a mouseover or hover first to trigger a change that makes the thing selectable.

Comment: Based on the class name this is part of an ExtJS grid control which is usually done via a table.  The easiest way to find this thing may be by other content on the same row.  Also it is entirely possible you need to click on the div' not the image inside it.  Lastly you may be able to identify the image based on its src value.

Answer (score 2):

You can click on it by the class or a partial match of the class.

```
@browser.image(:class=>/folder-action-add folder-action/).click
```

Here is a list of the [identifiers you can use for watir](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/HTML+Elements+Supported+by+Watir), I think it's mostly the same for watir-webdriver.

Answer (score 0):

So far, you haven't got a consistent way of actually identifying the element.  From what you've said in the comments, you've tried the 'text' attribute which doesn't exist, and the 'id' attribute which is auto generated and different every time.

You need to find a way of consistently identifying the element.  It's usually preferable to use a semantic class on the element to make styling and testing easier and less brittle.  You have a few classes declared, perhaps 'folder-action-add' expresses the intent of the button clearly?  If not, you could add one such as 'add-music-file'.

Then you should be able to use watir to select an element by it's class, I'm not familiar with the syntax but at a guess, `@browser.image(:class => 'add-music-file')` might do the job.